# Align span elements centered post translateX

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am attempting to push a set of span elements (created with ng-repeat) to a certain calculated position on the x-axis.

This is being done in a directive where the position for each element is calculated based on some heuristics.

However, these elements *are* not centered, but rather left aligned. This poses a problem when there is text (of variable length) that needs to be centered under the aforementioned position.

Intuitively, one could calculate the width of the element containing the text, and offset that from the translateX position, however the html is compiled in the directive, and changes post render would cause a noticeable flicker.

In below code, you can imagine as though the vertical | represent the mid-point position for which the text should be centered under.

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="varApp" ng-controller="TodoCtrl"> 
  <div class="outter">
    <span class="inner" ng-repeat="i in items track by $index" ng-if="i.value != null" ng-style="i.style">
      {{i.value}}
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="outter2">
    <span class="inner" ng-repeat="i in items track by $index" ng-style="i.style">|</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 16px !important;
}

.outter2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 16px !important;
}

.inner {
  posiiton: absolute;
  cursor: default;
  z-index: 1
  color: #red;
}
```

JavaScript (fragment):

```
angular.module('varApp', [])
.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope) {
    var items = $scope.items = [];

  for(var i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
    var string = new Array(i).join('a');
    items.push({
        value: string,
      style: {
        // should be transform: translateX(calcValue(el))
        marginLeft: (i * 10) + "px"
      }
    })
  }
});
```

I have reproduced the example to a bare minimum, you can find it here;
http://jsfiddle.net/w3fs8efe/90/

**UPDATE:**

I have tried to switch over to using a "box" with the width set to that of the starting point to the *next* elements start point, essentially a table with columns, the problem now however is that the lat element does not get centered as the width gets broken down to fit to the parent element.

In other words, still no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get what I wanted by putting the text content inside a span whose width is equal to the offset between start and end position.

Javascript:

```
angular.module('varApp', [])
.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope) {
    var items = $scope.items = [];

  for(var i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
    var string = new Array(i).join('a');
    items.push({
        value: string,
      style: {
        // should be transform: translateX(calcValue(el))
        marginLeft: (i * 100) + "px",
        minWidth: ((i+1) * 100) - (i * 100)
      }
    })
  }
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w3fs8efe/91/